# MariaDB/SQL query for the Leaf nodes

Tags: sql, select, mariadb, hierarchical-data

I have a DB  structure like this:

id  -  parent_id    - root_id   - status

The root_id is the root function's id which does not have any parent or any root. It may or may not have any children. 
The parent_id is the children's parent_id. parent_id and root_id can be the same.

So I need a SQL query to find all the leaf nodes. FYI, root operation can also be a leaf node in case it does not have any children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` to filter on rows whose `id` does not appear in column `parent_id`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.status = 'ongoing'
    and not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.parent_id = t.id)
```

Comment: Still does not produce the expected output .. It also fetches the root operations ...
if the id has children then it should not be a leaf anymore. but with this query it also fetched the root functions and its children

Comment: @AHMForhadulIslam: it depends on your data is layed out... It would help if you could provide a few rows of sample data (and the corresponding expected result) so we can sort this out.